# Which ubuntu 12.04.3 is best for Device lc2430i ?

Tags: 12.04, laptop, intel, cpu, lts

Which Ubuntu version should I download for new Linux-certified laptop ? 

Device Name: lc2430i

MEMORY: 3.8GiB

Processor:3rd Generation Intel Core i5-3210M CPU @ 2.5GHZ X 4 (3MB L3Cache,2C+HT)

OS TYPE: 64-bit
Graphics: Intel Ivy bridge Mobile
Disk: 483.8GB

Note: This Laptop came with Ubuntu 13.04 but we ordered 12.04 LTS, I want the Long Term System not systems that only have support for 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

go for i386 thats the safetst bet, though i see your laptop does supprt 64bit, you can try downloading any of the i386/x86_64 desktop iso and ready to go.